# Cant use $this->_forward() on zend

Tags: zend-framework, forward

i am trying to use $this->_forward($action,$controller); at my view, but i am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name '_forward' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/;C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/dentallab/application/modules/default/views\helpers/' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\libraries\Zend_Framework_1\1.12.3\library\Zend\Loader\PluginLoader.php:412

Stack trace:  
#0 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\libraries\Zend_Framework_1\1.12.3\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(1182): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('_forward') 
#1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\libraries\Zend_Framework_1\1.12.3\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(618): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', '_forward') 
#2 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\libraries\Zend_Framework_1\1.12.3\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(344): Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('_forward') 
#3 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\dentallab\application\modules\default\views\scripts\institucional\index.phtml in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\libraries\Zend_Framework_1\1.12.3\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 336
```

if anyone can help me, i appreciate!

Comment: it will work from controller..

Comment: is there a way to insert a view inside my view? Like $this->render() but i need this new view to be processed with its controller, otherwise it is not much helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Action View Helper` for this situation

in the view,
`<?php echo $this->action('action',
                                 'controller',
                                 'module',
                                 array('param' => 10)); ?>`

Here is the link to the ZF manual [Action View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action)

Comment: i dont know why, but $this->action() is forcing my browser to download the page! DO you know how to fix it?

Comment: It was calling action() with an empty action in the parameter, this causes the browser to download the website.